# \hspace*{-9cm} not working in columns environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, columns

[image]

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The Euclidian Algorithm}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{columns}[t]
  \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
  \vspace*{-2cm}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Algorithm}
   \[ a=q_1b+r_1 \quad\quad 0<r_1<b \]
   \[ b=q_2r_1+r_2 \quad\quad 0<r_2<r_1 \]
   \[ r_1=q_2r_2+r_3 \quad\quad 0<r_3<r_2 \]
   \[ r_{n-2}=q_nr_{n-1}+r_n \quad\quad 0<r_n<r_{n-1} \]
    \[ r_{n-1}=q_{n+1}r_n+0 \]
    \[ d=gcd(a,b)=r_n\]
  \end{exampleblock}
  \end{column}
 \begin{column}{0.33\linewidth}
  \hspace*{-9cm}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Example 1: gcd(10,63)}
   \[63=10.6+3\]
   \[10=3.3.+1\]
   \[3=3.1+0\]
  \end{exampleblock}
    \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.6\linewidth}
  \vspace*{-1cm}
\footnotesize
  \begin{exampleblock}{Example 2: gcd(1701,3768)}
   \[3768=1701.2+366\]
   \[1701=366.4+237\]
   \[366=237.1+129\]
   \[237=129.1+108\]
   \[129=108.1+21\]
   \[108=21.5+3\]
   \[21=3.7+0\]
  \end{exampleblock}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to position the `Example 1` column bellow the `Algorithm` and `Example 2` in right to the `Algorithm`.

I put `hspace*{-9cm}` left move the `Example 1` column left, but not moves.

Comment: Why don't you just put it into the same column if is supposed to sit below?

Comment: @marmot As they are different block(one is algorithm and one is example) I want to put in separate.

Comment: the position of the exampleblock after an hspace is the same as the position after `abc` it does not move to the right or left as it starts a new pararaph, below, the `\hspace*` here just starts a (white) paragraph with no text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this the layout you are looking for?

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The Euclidian Algorithm}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Algorithm}
   \[ a=q_1b+r_1 \quad\quad 0<r_1<b \]
   \[ b=q_2r_1+r_2 \quad\quad 0<r_2<r_1 \]
   \[ r_1=q_2r_2+r_3 \quad\quad 0<r_3<r_2 \]
   \[ r_{n-2}=q_nr_{n-1}+r_n \quad\quad 0<r_n<r_{n-1} \]
    \[ r_{n-1}=q_{n+1}r_n+0 \]
    \[ d=gcd(a,b)=r_n\]
  \end{exampleblock}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Example 1: gcd(10,63)}
     \[63=10.6+3\]
     \[10=3.3.+1\]
     \[3=3.1+0\]
    \end{exampleblock}
  \end{column}
 \begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Example 2: gcd(1701,3768)}
     \[3768=1701.2+366\]
     \[1701=366.4+237\]
     \[366=237.1+129\]
     \[237=129.1+108\]
     \[129=108.1+21\]
     \[108=21.5+3\]
     \[21=3.7+0\]
    \end{exampleblock}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And as already said for you previous question: you don't need `xcolor` with beamer